# vb.net store/persist time series to disk

Tags: database, vb.net

I develop a vb.net application which produces around 100-200 columns of time series data with up to 50000 rows (I have 100-200 variables that vary over up to 50000 time steps). In the application I can put this data into a dataset, or using a dictionary or lists. This all works fine and fast enough.

Now I need to write all the data to the disk for later use/analysis. The information needed is: variable name, time ID and double value. I've come across several posts about databases etc. But I am still not sure what might be the most (time)efficient way to persist this data. I tried saving the data in a dataset and then write to xml or using a binaryformatter writing to binary files. This works, however I get rather large files and reading the data back takes too long.
I also tried writing the data in a dictionary(of string, dictionary(of integer, double). String would be the column name/ variable name, intger would be the time ID and double would be the actual value. If I write this using a binaryformatter performance also is not the best. It takes around 30s to read in the file (40000 rows, 60 columns)..

Maybe I should add: when I read in data after storing it on the disk I only need to plot the data, show it in a datagridview and calculate maxima minima and sums, so nothing fancy..

I have not yet tried to use SQLite to persist the data in a database. I am not familiar with SQLite and would like to get an opinion of you whether this might be the faster solution.

Or is there any other faster way?

Comment: What is the source of the data?  As written, this isnt really a programming question

Comment: The data is the outcome of a simulation of my .net application. In the application I can put the data in a dataset or whatever container necessary to efficiently write it to the disk.

Answer (score 0):

Try CSV (comma separated values) format. Its widely supported and has little overhead.

However you should really use a database here if you want performance.

Comment: Thats a good way of doing it. Here is another good one: https://www.codeproject.com/Tips/665519/Writing-a-DataTable-to-a-CSV-File